# rails: has_and_belongs_to_many not saving associated objects (null in join table)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

Rails 4. I got an `Authentication` model

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posting_groups
  ...
end
```

and a `PostingGroup` model

```
class PostingGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authentications
  ...
end
```

The migration for the join table look like this:

```
def change
  create_table :authentications_posting_groups, id: false do |t|
    t.belongs_to :posting_group
    t.belongs_to :authentication
  end
end
```

Neither the `Authentication` nor the `PostingGroup` tables need references to each other or to the join table, so there's no relevant information in them. When updating the `PostingGroups` of an `Authentication` I do the following:

```
def update
  @authentication.update_attributes(authentication_params)
end
def authentication_params
    params.require(:other_unimportant_stuff, posting_groups: [])
end
```

During the execution of the `update` action, `params` is as follows:

> {"authentication"=>{"posting_groups"=>["17", "18"]}, 
>   "stuff"=>"more stuff}

...where, 17 and 18 are the ids of the posting groups which should be saved. And, indeed, the `@authentication` variable in `update` contains the desired `PostingGroups` and `update_attributes` returns true. However, `Authentication.find(id).posting_groups` (i.e. what *actually* was stored in the db) returns an empty set. Additionally, checking the `authentications_posting_groups` table shows the following:

```
posting_group_id    authentication_id   
              17    NULL
              18    NULL
```

For some weird reason the `authentication_id` is never making it to the db, which is funny because the save was triggered on this object in the first place. It's not the first time I encounter this problem but rather the second, the first time we noticed that everything worked fine (that is, those `NULL` didn't pop up in the db) when *creating* what in this scenario is the `Authentication`, but the same happened on `update`. On that occasion a hack was implemented re-creating the object (on `create` everything is OK!!), but here that's not an option. I'd immensely appreciate any pointers because this is driving us mad. Thanks.

Edit - here's the form which is triggering the whole thing:

```
= form_for authentication, remote: true do |f|
  = f.select :posting_groups, options_for_select(@posting_groups.map {|pg| [ pg.name, pg.id ] }), {}, multiple: true, class: "form-control posting_groups_select"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should permit posting_group_ids and pass posting_group_ids

Controller

```
def update
  @authentication.update_attributes(authentication_params)
end
def authentication_params
    params.require(:other_unimportant_stuff, posting_group_ids: [])
end
```

View

```
= form_for authentication, remote: true do |f|
  = f.select :posting_group_ids, options_for_select(@posting_groups.map {|pg| [ pg.name, pg.id ] }), {}, multiple: true, class: "form-control posting_groups_select"
```

Comment: Tried this as well...same behaviour. Authentication_id in join table is NULL.

Comment: Have you tried to check if authentication has those posting_groups or if particular posting_group has authentication, maybe you are not looking the right way to the table data. Try open rails console and check if data is added?

Comment: Yep I did, the join table is actually filled out, only with authentication_id set to null (therefore authentication.posting_groups is an empty set, as is posting_group.authentications)

Comment: Also, Authentication.new(posting_groups: [PostingGroup.find(1)]).save works perfectly (that is, the join table has both fields filled out). Updating it results in a null in authentication_id. WTF?

Comment: try to use update! to see if some errors get generated

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Field 'authentication_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `authentications_posting_groups` (`posting_group_id`) VALUES (2)      same old story. authentication_id does not reach the db

Comment: I changed the has_and_belongs_to_many to a has_many :through. Same results. Seriously...

Comment: I really can't think what is the problem, it seems like object '@authentication' those not have id, is that even possible? You saw it generated error no default value for authentication_id when you used update! method.

Comment: no no, it definitely has an id (I'm working with already persisted objects, therefore the problem - it's an update). I solved this by executing raw sql commands, mimicking what rails should do...dirty, but I need to push this forward.

Answer (score 0):

```
params.require(:other_unimportant_stuff, posting_group_ids: [])
```

Notice the ids.

You're passing in `posting_group_ids` as per your params but your parameters are set to `posting_groups` so strong parameters will filter it out.

Comment: sorry! that was a typo, I've been trying some different approaches and that was one of them. It should be posting_groups: [] and I'm updating my question.